# gems error when attempting to run rails for the first time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

While trying to install rails I get this error. I also was not able to install sqlite3 so I simply tried: gem install sqlite3 -- And it seemed that it worked.
**Error:**

```
C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:60:in `fetch': No such file or directory - bs_fetch:
open_current_file:fstat (Errno::ENOENT)
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:60:in `fetch'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:85:in `load_iseq'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/3.1.0/yaml.rb:4:in `<main>'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/yaml.rb:58:in `init!'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/yaml.rb:38:in `install!'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache.rb:26:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap.rb:71:in `setup'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap.rb:112:in `default_setup'
        from C:/Ruby31-x64/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/bootsnap-1.10.3/lib/bootsnap/setup.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Users/cctv0/Desktop/ruby-projects/friends/friends/config/boot.rb:4:in `require'
        from C:/Users/cctv0/Desktop/ruby-projects/friends/friends/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
        from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Same here. No idea why.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, I solved it by changing the project path `C:\rails\my-first-app`